# undefined reference to `jack_client_close`, et al

Tags: audio, gcc, linker, jack

I'm trying to follow [this](http://dis-dot-dat.net/index.cgi?item=/jacktuts/starting/compiling) introductory tutorial on jack (audio server for linux). In the tutorial, the author explains that you should use `pkg-config` to find the `cflags` and `libs` for jack, making the `gcc` command like this:

```
gcc -o simple_client `pkg-config --cflags --libs jack` simple_client.c
```

which gives the output:

```
/tmp/ccyuOC0u.o: In function `signal_handler':
simple_client.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `jack_client_close'
/tmp/ccyuOC0u.o: In function `process':
simple_client.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `jack_port_get_buffer'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `jack_port_get_buffer'
/tmp/ccyuOC0u.o: In function `main':
simple_client.c:(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `sin'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x2c1): undefined reference to `jack_client_open'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x372): undefined reference to `jack_get_client_name'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to `jack_set_process_callback'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x3ca): undefined reference to `jack_on_shutdown'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x3ee): undefined reference to `jack_port_register'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x419): undefined reference to `jack_port_register'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x475): undefined reference to `jack_activate'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x4c5): undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x514): undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to `jack_connect'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x56e): undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `jack_connect'
simple_client.c:(.text+0x5ba): undefined reference to `jack_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not very experienced using gcc or writing c programs generally (most of my experience has been with javascript, clojure, java, python, and php). What I gather from this and my research into it is that some libraries are missing or linked incorrectly (not sure which).

So just running `pkg-config --cflags --libs jack` on my machine, I get:

```
-ljack
```

In the tutorial referenced above, the author demonstrates the same method for gleaning the libs to be linked for jack, but his output looks like this:

```
-ljack -lpthread -ldl -lrt
```

Not sure what pthread is, but I think dl is dsp-loader, and rt has something to do with realtime. I've searched in several directories called `/lib` and haven't come across anything for these other libs, so I don't think they exist on my machine. However, it seems strange to me that calling `pkg-config` doesn't make any mention of them. How should I go about finding these libs? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Does this command work: `gcc -o simple_client $(pkg-config --cflags --libs jack) -ljack -lpthread -ldl -lrt simple_client.c` ?

Comment: do you mind editing the posting with the errors you get when you ran the above gcc command ? It would be useful information to debug what is going wrong.

Comment: the output is identical

Comment: What is the output from `ls -l /usr/lib/libjack.so*` or if your system  has a `/usr/lib64` and you're running 64-bit `ls -l /usr/lib64/libjack.so*` ?

Comment: I don't seem to have these options. I have `/lib64` by itself, which doesn't contain libjack.so*, I have `/usr/lib/` but no libjack anything, and I have `/usr/lib32` and again no libjack anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25454/discussion-between-tuxdude-and-tjb1982)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link command line is wrong, try this one instead:

```
gcc -o simple_client simple_client.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs jack`
```

The order of archive libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).